# I can't figure out how my Django React Create Form returns, 'Unsupported Media Type: /api/auctions/'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, rest

My Django REST API uploads an auction correctly (including the required images) when I make a post request in Postman. However, my React auctioncreateform.js file does not successfully create an auction and instead returns the error below: 'Unsupported Media Type: /api/auctions/'.

THE FORM WORKS AS INTENDED when I remove the uploaded_images values/attributes from the project. The post request through the form shows an error when I include the uploaded_images field.

`console.log(values);` in my auctioncreateform.js returns these:

```
bestdeals: false

car_specification: [12] (1)

category: 1

duration: 7

make: 1

model: 1

name: "jhjh"

overview: "<p>gfgfg</p>"

reserveprice: 0

start_time: "2023-05-27T10:53"

starting_price: 0

type: "SUV"

uploaded_images: Array (1)
0 File {path: "BM945737_dec96f.jpeg", name: "BM945737_dec96f.jpeg", lastModified: 1684687221000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 83369, …}

Array Prototype

year: "2012"
```

Below is my auctioncreateform.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx"
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik"
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack"
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';



import axios from "axios";
import FilesDropzone from "../../../../components/Files-Dropzone";

import { postAuctionAxios } from '../../../../services/AuctionService'
import { YupAuctionValidation } from "./schema/YupAuctionValidation"
import { AuctionDefaultValue } from "./schema/AuctionDefaultValue"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router"



const AuctionCreateForm = props => {
 ....
  return (
    <Container>

    <Formik
      initialValues={AuctionDefaultValue}
      validationSchema={YupAuctionValidation}
      onSubmit={async (values, formikHelpers) => {
        console.log(values);

        
        try {
          const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
          console.log(token)
          const { uploaded_images, ...otherValues } = values;
          console.log('Uploaded Images:', uploaded_images);
          
          await postAuctionAxios(values, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } });


          
          formikHelpers.setStatus({ success: true })
          formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false)
          enqueueSnackbar("Auction Created", {
            variant: "success"
          })
          .push("list-auctions")
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Something happened. Please try again.")
          setError(err.message)
          formikHelpers.setStatus({ success: false })
          formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false)
        }
        //console.log(err.message)
      }}
      
    >
      {formikProps => (
        <form onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit} className="">
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} lg={8}>
      .....
              <Box mt={3}>
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader title="Upload Images" />
                  <Divider />
                  <CardContent>
                  <FilesDropzone onFilesChange={(files) => formikProps.setFieldValue('uploaded_images', files)} />
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Box>
              
             ....
       
          <Box mt={2}>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              disabled={formikProps.isSubmitting}
            >
              Create auction
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
    )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AuctionCreateForm;
```

My imported Dropzone.js component is as follows:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import { Box, Typography, List, ListItem, ListItemAvatar, Avatar, ListItemText, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { Delete as DeleteIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";

const FilesDropzone = ({ onFilesChange }) => {
  const handleDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      if (onFilesChange) {
        onFilesChange(acceptedFiles);
      }
    },
    [onFilesChange]
  );

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, acceptedFiles } = useDropzone({
    onDrop: handleDrop,
    accept: 'image/*',
    multiple: true,
  });

  const handleRemoveFile = (index) => {
    if (onFilesChange) {
      const updatedFiles = [...acceptedFiles];
      updatedFiles.splice(index, 1);
      onFilesChange(updatedFiles);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box {...getRootProps()} p={2} border={1} borderColor="grey.400" borderRadius={4}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {isDragActive ? (
        <Typography variant="body1">Drop the files here...</Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography variant="body1">Drag and drop files here or click to browse</Typography>
      )}
      {acceptedFiles.length > 0 && (
        <Box mt={2}>
          <List>
            {acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => (
              <ListItem key={index}>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar variant="rounded" src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} />
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText primary={file.name} secondary={`${(file.size / 1024).toFixed(2)} KB`} />
                <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemoveFile(index)}>
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Box>
      )}
    </Box>
 
};

export default FilesDropzone;
```

Please let me know if you need more code including the backend. I can't find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciation to anyone that viewed my question. I figured out the answer. The solution is to append values in form of formData as follows:

```
  try {
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
          console.log(token);
      
          const formData = new FormData();
          values.uploaded_images.forEach((file, index) => {
            formData.append(`uploaded_images[${index}]`, file);
          });
          // Append other form fields to the formData object
       
          formData.append('category', values.category);
          formData.append('make', values.make);
       
          // ... append other form fields
      
          const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auctions/', formData, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
          });
      
          formikHelpers.setStatus({ success: true });
          formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false);
          enqueueSnackbar('Auction Created', {
            variant: 'success',
          });
          // Redirect or perform any other necessary action
          console.log(response)
          console.log('Auction created:', response.data);
          navigate('list-auctions');
        } catch (err) {
          alert('Something happened. Please try again.');
          setError(err.message);
          formikHelpers.setStatus({ success: false });
          formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false);
        }
        //console.log(err.message)
      }}
```